# Ubercart no product in your cart

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, ubercart

I am using Drupal 6 with Ubercart and [uc_hotel](http://drupal.org/project/uc_hotel) module.

Now problem is when I am trying to book now it says there is no product in your shopping cart. 
But when I am trying to book now as a admin it shows products in my cart.

I checked the permissions too ...

Anybody have idea how to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

You have to Enable anonymous checkout (users can checkout without logging in).

present under admin/store/settings/checkout/edit/basic.

hope it will help you!!!